# Maximum usage USB and GPIO power consumption

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, power-management

I use a raspberry Pi3B+ for a home automation installation. On which I have connected several peripherals. In particular an RFID reader and an OLED screen.  But I notice that after a while, these devices start to not respond anymore. So I reboot, but they do not turn on again. The only way to turn them back on is to unplug/plug the raspberry directly.
Is it possible that there are "voltage losses" over time? Do the peripherals consume too much power, so the raspberry fails?
Here is the list of peripherals connected to the rasp:

USB :

- Conbee 2
- Huawei 3372 dongle
- Stick CC2531

GPIO :

- RFID RC522
- Oled screen SSD1306
- Clock module DS1306
- A buzzer

I wonder if it's not all this that pushes the rapberry to its limits. But I don't know its capacity to manage all these peripherals

Comment: is the pi reporting undervoltage errors?  how do you reboot? shutdown -r command or?  have you tried unplugging the peripherals one at a time to see if one particular item is the cause?

Answer (score 2):

If in doubt with power consumption the first step is to use a powered USB hub for all USB devices.